# How to use post method for login and to pass parameters in android

Tags: android, post, httpurlconnection

I am trying to create a user login bu using the following credentials. I got a url from server but am unable to use post method please give me some code snippet for me.

Thanks in advance.

parameters to be passed: "user_name": "8013977",
                       "user_pass":"8013977"

My code snippet:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxxxxxxx:8080/hanwha/player/login.on";

public static final String KEY_USERNAME="user_name";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD="user_pass";

private EditText editTextUsername;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private Button buttonLogin;

private String username;
private String password ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

    buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
}


private void userLogin() {

    username = editTextUsername.getText().toString();

    Log.e(KEY_USERNAME , username);

    password ="8013977";
    Log.e(KEY_PASSWORD , password);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("eee", "response: " + response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params  = new HashMap<String,String>();
            params.put("user_name","8013977");
            params.put("user_pass","8013977");
            return params ;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void openProfile(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityUserProfile.class);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_USERNAME, username);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    userLogin();
}
```

}

Comment: do you get an error message when you try to run this code?

Comment: yes in postdata string I used targetgraduate there am getting error.Instaed of that how to use my credentials as parameters

Comment: @Mounika why don't you use volley library

Comment: I tried with that but am not getting so am using asynctask, its very urgent so am using old method

Comment: Remove this line from your code" String data = params[0];"

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code

```
BasicNameValuePair _id = new BasicNameValuePair(
            "id", id);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairList.add(_id);
    JSONObject jobj = JSONfunctions.getPostUrl(yourUrl, nameValuePairList);
```

---

```
public static JSONObject getPostUrl(String url,
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList) {
    JSONObject jObject = null;
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();


    // HttpPost argument
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    try {
        .
        UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                nameValuePairList);


        httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

        try {

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);


            InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    inputStreamReader);

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String bufferedStrChunk = null;

            while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
            }
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {

             cpe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {

             ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        // System.out
        // .println("An Exception given because of UrlEncodedFormEntity argument :"
        // + uee);
        // uee.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jObject;
}
```

Comment: httppost is deprecated, so am not getting

Comment: you can try  URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
   } finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }

Comment: yes thats what I posted but how to pass that parameters in my code snippet ,please give me some suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I use this login function,with POST;implements Volley

```
private void login() {
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(context, null, "Authenticating.Please wait...",true,true);
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                "your login url", new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "response: " + response);

                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                    // check for error flag
                    if (obj.getString("error").equals("false")) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        loading.dismiss();
                        JSONObject userObj = obj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String id=userObj.getString("requestor_id");
                        String nam= userObj.getString("name");
                        String ema=userObj.getString("email");
                        User user = new User(id,nam,ema);
                        // storing user in shared preferences
                        MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().storeUser(user);
                        if(myPreferenceManager.isFirstLaunch()){
                            reRegisterGCM(nam,ema);
                            myPreferenceManager.setIsFirstLaunch(false);
                        }
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class));
                        finish();

                    } else {
                        // login error - simply toast the message
                        loading.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + obj.getJSONObject("error").getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json parse error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                loading.dismiss();
                Log.e(TAG, "Volley error: " + error.getMessage() + ", code: " + networkResponse+" and "+error.getMessage());
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Volley error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override

            public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("user_name","8013977");
                params.put("user_pass","8013977");

                Log.e(TAG, "params: " + params.toString());
                return params;
            }
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
        };
        //Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
    }
```

Comment: Am using volley but am getting wrong response, please tell me what to do now

Comment: response: {"result_code":"US02E500","result_msg":"Unexpected character ('u' (code 117)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: java.io.StringReader@200c1e7c; line: 1, column: 2]"}

Comment: @Mounika add this method in your volley,as shown i my code

Comment: @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Not sure why it's not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I still suggest you to use Volley Library but as you say it is very urgent you can use name value pair for posting parameters.
You can use the following code:

```
HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse httpResponse;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs; 

class task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>{

        @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // show progress dialog
            }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                httppost = new HttpPost("http://yourUrl");
                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_name", "8013977"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_pass":"8013977"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                res = httpclient.execute(httppost,responseHandler);
                Log.e("Response",res);  

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
                    // update UI
            }
    }
```

Comment: Same code I used but http post is deprecating , so that is showing null

Comment: @Mounika then you have to use volley no other option left as per my knowledge.

Comment: @Mounika check this [Volley Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/) Easy to understand and implement. Won't gonna take much time at all.

Comment: actually its a post method not a get method